# ошибка установки библиотеки вк туннель vk-tunnel

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, npm, библиотеки, vk-mini-apps

пытаюсь установить вк-туннель `npm install @vkontakte/vk-tunnel`

терминал выдает кучу ошибок (причем библиотека **bridge** установилась нормально). пробовала устанавливать глобально `npm install @vkontakte/vk-tunnel -g`, `npm install @vkontakte/vk-tunnel --include=dev`, не помогает.

слышала, что существует проблема с запуском пакета на windows (у меня винда) - для запуска нужно доставить некоторые программы и пакеты. попробовала сделать это через докер - тоже выдает ошибку.

вот как выглядит терминал, когда пытаюсь установить вк туннель `npm install @vkontakte/vk-tunnel` :

```
npm WARN cleanup Failed to remove some directories [
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'V:\\PROGRAMMING\\vk-app\\node_modules\\@vkontakte\\vk-tunnel\\node_modules\\ext',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'V:\PROGRAMMING\vk-app\node_modules\@vkontakte\vk-tunnel\node_modules\ext\node_modules'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',      
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'V:\\PROGRAMMING\\vk-app\\node_modules\\@vkontakte\\vk-tunnel\\node_modules\\ext\\node_modules'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'V:\\PROGRAMMING\\vk-app\\node_modules\\@vkontakte\\vk-tunnel\\node_modules',
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'V:\PROGRAMMING\vk-app\node_modules\@vkontakte\vk-tunnel\node_modules\resolve\test\resolver\punycode'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',      
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'V:\\PROGRAMMING\\vk-app\\node_modules\\@vkontakte\\vk-tunnel\\node_modules\\resolve\\test\\resolver\\punycode'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ],
npm WARN cleanup   [
npm WARN cleanup     'V:\\PROGRAMMING\\vk-app\\node_modules\\@vkontakte\\vk-tunnel',        
npm WARN cleanup     [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir 'V:\PROGRAMMING\vk-app\node_modules\@vkontakte\vk-tunnel\node_modules\resolve\test\resolver\punycode'] {
npm WARN cleanup       errno: -4048,
npm WARN cleanup       code: 'EPERM',
npm WARN cleanup       syscall: 'rmdir',      
npm WARN cleanup       path: 'V:\\PROGRAMMING\\vk-app\\node_modules\\@vkontakte\\vk-tunnel\\node_modules\\resolve\\test\\resolver\\punycode'
npm WARN cleanup     }
npm WARN cleanup   ]
npm WARN cleanup ]
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path V:\PROGRAMMING\vk-app\node_modules\@vkontakte\vk-tunnel\node_modules\websocket
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1       
npm ERR! gyp info using node@20.11.1 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.3 found at "C:\Python311\python.exe"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS msvs_version not set from command line or npm config
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS checking VS2019 (16.11.33529.622) found at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"  
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found "Visual Studio C++ core features"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - found VC++ toolset: v142
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS - missing any Windows SDK
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS could not find a version of Visual Studio 2017 or newer to use    
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2015 as it is only supported up to Node.js 18   
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8    
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************    
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************    
npm ERR! gyp ERR! find VS
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:113:11)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at VisualStudioFinder.findVisualStudio (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-visualstudio.js:69:17)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async createBuildDir (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:69:26)   
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at async run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js:81:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd V:\PROGRAMMING\vk-app\node_modules\@vkontakte\vk-tunnel\node_modules\websocket
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v20.11.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

знает ли кто-нибудь решение этой проблемы? (пишу программу на js)

Comment: `Error: Could not find any Visual Studio installation to use` - требуется перевод?